# Tkinter - Selecting an item from a Treeview using single click instead of double click (Callback on Treeview item selection)

Tags: python, tkinter, tk-toolkit, ttk

When you want to select an item in a Treeview, you usually use the double-click:

```
def print_element(event):
    print(my_treeview.selection()[0])
my_treeview.bind("<Double-1>", print_element)
```

Today I tried to do the same but using a single click instead:

```
my_treeview.bind("<Button-1>", print_element)
```

But it wouldn't work. The output was just an empty tuple.
I started to search online for an explanation... why is it not working?

EDIT:
My goal was actually to `do something` every time a treeview item was selected.

- I proposed a solution myself using the `identify()` function of Tkinter
- Another user proposed to use the Tkinter callback `<ButtonRelease-1>` which is much more appropriate
- Finally, a third user focused his answer on using the Tkinter callback `<<TreeviewSelect>>`, which is for sure the best option

Comment: Does this answer your question? [tkinter-treeview-click-event-for-selected-item](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40533812)

Comment: You should bind on `<ButtonRelease-1>` or `<<TreeviewSelect>>` instead.

Comment: @acw1668 I didn't think about using that event in that way. What you suggest is probably the pythonic way to do it. If you leave it an answer, I will accept yours

Comment: Are you asking how to _select_ an item in a treeview on click? Treeview does that automatically for you. Or, are you asking how to run a function whenever something is selected in the Treeview?

Comment: @BryanOakley my goal is to obtain a specific value from the selected item, in the same moment it is selected, without a need for the doubleclick

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The reason it doesn't work the way you expect is because your custom single-click binding happens before the default behavior. So, when your single-click is processed, that happens before an item is selected. The second time you click, your function will print the previously selected item.

If you want to have a function called when an item is selected, you should bind to `<<TreeviewSelect>>`, which will fire immediately after the user selects an item with a single click or via the keyboard.

The default behavior of a treeview supports selecting multiple items at once, so the following code will print out the text of all of the selected items as a list, even if only a single item is selected. You can, of course, modify this to only print out the first selected item if you so desire.

```
def print_element(event):
    tree = event.widget
    selection = [tree.item(item)["text"] for item in tree.selection()]
    print("selected items:", selection)

tree.bind("<<TreeviewSelect>>", print_element)
```

Answer (score 1):

It is because the selection is not set yet when the `<Button-1>` (it is the same as `<ButtonPress-1>`, i.e. when the mouse button 1 *is pressed and not released*) event callback is called.

You should bind on `<ButtonRelease-1>` or `<<TreeviewSelect>>` instead as the selection is set when the event callback is being executed.

Comment: I have to pick Bryan answer because he provided a code solution, and focused his answer to TreeviewSelect (I didn't even pay attention to it when you mentioned it). Still, kudos for bringing up ButtonRelease-1

Answer (score 0):

### Why it doesn't work

When you click an item in a treeview, that item is still not in a SELECTED status in the moment the callback is activated. You are changing the status in that very moment.

Using a double-click, the first click change the status, and at the second click you are activating your callback, so the status has already been changed.

### How can it work

Kudos to [this website](https://www.daniweb.com/programming/software-development/threads/431464/right-click-on-treeview-to-select-item-currently-hovered-over)

In short,

```
def print_element(event):
    print(my_treeview.identify('item', e.x, e.y))
my_treeview.bind("<Button-1>", print_element)
```

This time, `print_element()` will check the coordinates of the mouse, and will discover the selected item check what is under the mouse. Nice and clean!